# How to use implicit function theorem and Lagrange multiplier to prove there exists a local minimum?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima, implicit-function-theorem

Assume f(x,y) and g(x,y) are two smooth functions on $R^2$

Let
$$S=\left \{ (x,y)|f(x,y)=0 \right \} $$,
and
$$p=(a,b)\in S$$

such that

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (p) = -4,\space\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (p) = 2,\space\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} (p) = 12,\space \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} (p)=-6$$

And

$$\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}f(p)  &  \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}f(p)  \\  \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y\partial x}f(p)  & \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}f(p)\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 &2 \\ 2 &4\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}g(p)  &  \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}g(p)  \\  \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y\partial x}g(p)  & \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}g(p)\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 3&-1 \\ -1 &2\end{bmatrix}$$

How to prove $ \exists \space R> 0 $ such that  $\forall \space q \in {S}\cap\left \{(x,y)| x^2+y^2< R^2 \right \} $ there is always g(p)< g(q)

The only thing I am certain is we can prove this by implicit function theorem and Lagrange multiplier, but other than that, I have absolutely no clue where I should start. Could someone give me some hint?

Comment: The implicit function theorem tells you that $S$ is a curve through $p$, and has a unique tangent in the direction of a certain vector $\mathbf{u}$ at $p$. You then need to show that the directional derivative $D_{\mathbf{u}}g$ vanishes at $p$ also (otherwise there cannot be a local constained extremum). Then you can use the fact that the Hessian of $g$ at $p$ is positive definite to conclude. Or simply calculate the second derivative of $g$ at $p$ in the direction of $\mathbf{u}$ to ascertain that you have a local constrained minimum.

Comment: Thanks @aschepler. I somehow missed that on my first and second readings :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the implicit function theorem, there is a function $h$ such that $h(a)=b$ and $f(x,h(x))=0$ for all $x$ near $a$. If you differentiate and use the chain rule, you get
$$\partial_xf(x,h(x))+\partial_yf(x,h(x)))h’(x)=0$$ In particular, if you plug in $x=a$, you get that $h’(a)=2$.
You need to differentiate once more to compute $h’’(a)$.

Now consider the function $p(x)=g(x,h(x))$, which is the function $g$ restricted to the set $S$ near the point $p$. By Taylor’s formula of order two, you can write
$$p(x)=p(a)+p’(a)(x-a)+p’’(a)(x-a)^2/2+o((x-a)^2)$$
By the chain rule,
$$p’(x)=\partial_xg(x,h(x))+\partial_yg(x,h(x)))h’(x)$$
If you plug in $x=a$, you get $p’(a)=0$, so $a$ is a critical point of $p$.
Now you need to differentiate once more to compute $p’’(a)$ and prove that it is positive. Good luck with all the chain rules and computations!

Comment: But excuse me sir, I dont see there is any relation about $\left \{(x,y)| x^2+y^2< R^2 \right \}$???

Comment: It’s wrong. It should be $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2<R$. The implicit function theorem only works near the point $p$. There must be a misprint.

Comment: Hope you are right sir!